# Optimization for splitting one file into many small files

Tags: c#, file-io, io, text-parsing

I am trying to split a large file (comma delimited, each term wrapped in double quotes) into many smaller files, based on the key which is the first item in each record, there usually is more than 1 record with the same key.

This large file can range from 1GB to 2GB, the number of files generated can range from 10,000-30,000, each in a subfolder named after the key.

In C# I'm doing a StreamReader.ReadLine() on each line, concatenating the results until it reaches a different key (signaling the last of the data for the previous key), then calling a function to write the files asyncronously.  I am calling windows sort to sort these files to make the keys contiguous (so I only have to open files once) but it still takes like 20 minutes for the operation to complete.  Is there any way to speed this up?

```
sfd = new SaveFileDataDelegate(this.SaveFileData);



private void CSVParse(string filename, string unzippedFilePath, string feedname)
{
    StreamReader filestream = null;
    FileStream readerStream = null;
    try
    {
        readerStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 120000, FileOptions.SequentialScan);
        filestream = new StreamReader(readerStream, Encoding.UTF8, false, 120000);

        string tempstring = "";
        string buffer = "";
        string lastlotkey = "";
        IAsyncResult result = null;

        activityLog.Log("Parsing File: " + filename);

        while (((tempstring = filestream.ReadLine()) != null) || buffer != "")
        {
            if (tempstring == null)
            {
                tempstring = "";
            }
            string lotkey =  tempstring.Replace("\"","").Split(',').First();
            if (lotkey == tempstring && tempstring != "")
            {
                break;
            }
            if (lotkey == "DealerID")
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (lastlotkey == "")
            {
                lastlotkey = lotkey;
            }
            if ((lotkey != lastlotkey && buffer.Length > 0))
            {
                result = sfd.BeginInvoke(outputDirectory + @"\" + feedname + @"\" + lastlotkey + @"\" + (filename.Split('\\').Last()).Split('.').First() + ".txt", buffer, outputDirectory + @"\" + feedname + @"\" + lastlotkey,null,null);
                lastlotkey = lotkey;
                buffer = "";

                if (tempstring == "")
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (buffer.Length > 0)
            {
                buffer = buffer + "\r\n";
            }
            buffer = buffer + tempstring;
        }
        filestream.Close();
        readerStream.Close();
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(-1);
        }
        return;
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        activityLog.Log("Error Occurred:  " + e.ToString());
        if (filestream != null)
        {
            filestream.Close();
        }
        hadError = true;
        return;
    }
}


private void SaveFileData(string file, string buffer, string directory)
{
    // create file from last lot key with data from parsing, write, close, update lastlotkey
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    FileStream fs = null;
    StreamWriter temp = null;
    try
    {
        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 120000);
        }
        else
        {
            fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 120000);
        }
        temp = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8, 120000);
        temp.AutoFlush = false;
        temp.WriteLine(headerLine);
        temp.Write(buffer);
        temp.Flush();
        temp.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        activityLog.Log("Error Occurred:  " + e.ToString());
        if (fs != null)
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp.Close();
        }
        hadError = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I crawled Stack Overflow and the deepest bowels of the internet, and after profiling line by line I found that the string concatenation was actually the heavy lifting of the parsing routine (after the file copy and windows sort), replacing that with Stringbuilder made a tremendous improvement, total processing time dropped from 20 minutes (copy+sort+parse) to 5 minutes of copy+sort and 2 minutes of parsing, 7 minutes total.  A speed improvement of 130%

Comment: StringBuilder strikes again.  I wonder whether the time wasted trying to debug programs improperly written with String has esceeded the total memory saved in the world by String interning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the code that writes on the harddrive, how fast is it?
A lot of the slowdown will be because of the harddrive. get an ssd :P

Since you're looping a lot, I would limit the code inside the loop. Remove duplicate code and get as much code as possible outside the loop.

The 1st if is not needed sicne you are already checking for null in the while.

If you have a lot of similar lines then splitting might not be needed all the time. You could use .StartsWith instead.

If the file is consistent, you don't need to remove ". You can compare with ".

Since you are checking for an empty tempstring in the second if. Maybe you want to do this before the split, since it's useless to split an empty string.

A lot of the string manipulation you do to get the new filename can be done outside the loop.

Comment: this seemed to help a little, my processing time seemed to improve about 5%, I still get the sneaky suspicion my bottleneck is disk IO related, do you have any suggestions concerning the logic for opening/writing files, buffer sizes, etc?

Comment: @WestonM The only thing to make IO faster is to limit the number of read/write and to limit the movement of the needle (ex: reading/write a lot of different files will make the needle move more than just writing or reading one file). Or upgrading to faster hardware.